# How can I enable directory listing for a nexus3 raw repository?

Tags: nexus, nexus3, maven-site-plugin

In the past I was able to view the contents of my `raw` repository to which I upload my javadoc sites (through `dav:http://` using `mvn site-deploy`):

e.g. Accessing from the browser: http://myserver/nexus/content/sites/my-raw-repository/ would list the subdirectories.

Now (after admin upgraded to nexus 3.20) directory-listing does not work and I have to explicitly request for a resource page e.g.:

http://myserver/nexus/content/sites/my-raw-repository/artifact-site-name/1.0.0/apidocs/index.html

Is there a way to bring back the directory listing?

[This closed issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12531) says that nexus3 supports it, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. The  **repository browser url** is now differrent.

`content/sites` has become: `service/rest/repository/browse`.

(The old path is still available but with no directory listing. Based on the findings below, I guess it is deprecated)

I went to the `browse left-menu-option` -> `select the raw repository` -> clicked on the `Html View` link and it took me to the correct location.

The new **link is now:** http://myserver/nexus/service/rest/repository/browse/my-raw-repository/

**Something noteable** is that now when reaching the actual resource file (e.g. html),
that **resource file link is differrent:** http://myserver/nexus/repository/my-raw-repository/path/to/the/htmlpage.html

so instead of `service/rest/repository/browse/my-raw-repository/` it is `repository/my-raw-repository/` (which also does not support directory listing)